# Create variables with pre-specified correlation

Tags: r, correlation, simulation

I have a vector: `a<-rnorm(100)`

I would like to create 5 variables that are correlated with `a` to a different extent.

For example each of the 5 variables should have a correlation of `.5, .6, .7, .8, .9` with `a` respectively

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is, there are many ways to formulate (and thus solve) your problem. 
you are looking for the symmetric, psd matrix $A$ with $A_{1\cdot}=\{1,0.9,0.8,0.7,0.6,0.5\}$ and $A_{ii}=1,\;i=1,\ldots,6$.  There are many matrices satisfying these requirements. To pick one we need to add some more criterion/constraints. For example: if we add the criterion that we also want $|A|$ to be smallest and all the entries of $A\setminus \{A_{ii},A_{1\cdot}\}$ to be equal to some constant $\nu$. This is now a convex problem with a unique solution. In R you would write solve it as:

```
fx01<-function(nu,FixedRow){
    p<-lenght(FixedRow)
    a1<-matrix(nu,p,p)
    diag(a1)<-1
    a1[1,]<-a1[,1]<-FixedRow
    -det(a1)
}


FixedRow<-c(1,.9,.8,.7,.6,.5)
a1<-optimize(fx01,interval=c(-1,1),FixedRow=FixedRow)
```

and the value $\nu\approx0.6$, yielding the matrix:

```
nu<-a1$min
a2<-matrix(nu,6,6)
diag(a2)<-1
a2[1,]<-a2[,1]<-c(1,.9,.8,.7,.6,.5)


     a   b    c    d    e    f
a  1.0  0.9  0.8  0.7  0.6  0.5
b  0.9  1.0  0.6  0.6  0.6  0.6
c  0.8  0.6  1.0  0.6  0.6  0.6
d  0.7  0.6  0.6  1.0  0.6  0.6
e  0.6  0.6  0.6  0.6  1.0  0.6
f  0.5  0.6  0.6  0.6  0.6  1.0
```

which satisfies your requirements. Then, to actually generate your matrix of variables simply do:

```
library("MASS")
set.seed(123)
X<-mvrnorm(100,rep(0,6),a2,empirical=TRUE)
cor(X)
```

and you can check that, for example

cor(X[,1],X[,2])

returns 0.9.

Comment: what I actually meant is that the second variable should be a different set of random numbers that should be correlated with a. for example b<-a+rnorm(100,mean=0,sd=5) cor(a,b)=0.31 but instead of 0.31 I would like to predetermine what the correlation should be

Comment: yes, you can check that the second variable (in the example above) has a correlation with 'a' of 90% (as you originally asked)

Comment: right sorry. how easy is it to modify the code to apply to a different matrix length of A1? e.g. if I would like to have 6 instead of 5 correlated variables. is the problem very different?

Comment: not difficult at all. In fact I will rewrite the code to make the dimension of A a parameter!

Comment: is it also possible to have each of the 5 variables correlate with 'a' say .59 and each of the five variables correlate with each other .7?

Comment: @tuw: in general yes: the new constraint you set are also convex, so you just need to add a lagrangian for each of them to the objective function (though the  resulting problem may not have a solution)